# Android Navigation Bar Placement

Tags: android, navigationbar

I am creating an app that will always run in landscape. On tablets the system navigation bar is placed horizontally at the bottom of the screen, and on the phones it is placed vertically at the right end of the screen.

My question is if it is possible to control the placement of the navigation bar via a flag or with some code. I would like it to always appear either at the bottom, or to the right of the screen consistently, regardless of the device.